# 301 redirect through htaccess

Tags: php

I have moved my old site to new domain but google is still showing my previous links so
i made a htaccess file and made 301 redirect. Below is my htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It is redirecting old url to new url but it is not doing it page by page. Means if i am going to www.old.com/about.php then it is redirecting me to www.new.com/ but i want www.new.com/about.php to appear.

can u suggest me how to do this with the use of proper regular expression with minimal work ?

Comment: Remove the $ after old.com, it indicates the end of a string (and with /about.php the end is not there yet)

Answer (score 1):

This would maintain everything - the query string and the request path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It is not redirecting properly,for some of the pages. Pages are redirected to home page of new domain

Comment: @Durga Dutt: "some pages" is not helpful explanation at all. I use it for years with no issues

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use mod_rewrite at all. Simply use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName old.com
    ServerAlias www.old.com
    Redirect permanent / http://new.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Redirect` directive automatically preserves anything after the `/`.

Comment: This does, however, require the ability to add `VirtualHosts` (which not all shared hosting providers might allow).

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll leave my answer in case it applies to the next person who comes across this question and they *can* use virtual hosts.